# Online POST to a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, http, post

I am trying to make a HTTP POST to a WCF Service.But these Service is based on an another service. I referenced that service to my own service. Now I want to POST some data and get a response from my web service but it did not work.

```
    [OperationContract(Name ="GetData")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    UriTemplate = "GetData")]

    string GetData(string value);
```

These is my sample method.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public string GetData(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);                                  
        }
    }
```

and this is the content of my method.

Comment: i am trying to test my service. There is a site where i can do it https://www.hurl.it/ i choose post and paste my url enter the value as parameter and click send but it isnt work give me 400 bad request.

Comment: How you are passing the `body`? and what is `content-type`

Comment: actually i am new at wcf i dont know how to pass body can you explain me the i will be very appreciated.

Comment: whatever you're passing parameter that will be your json key. `{"value":"test"}` put a debugger and check you'll get `value = "test"`

Answer (score 0):

Verify following thing in your web.config

1. Make sure that your using webHttpBinding
2. Add end point behaviour as show below

   ```
   <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior>
               <webHttp/>
           </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   ```